# Call a variable from file A to file B in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function file that utilizes same variables as my second MATLAB script file. I want to call the variables that are in the script in order to use them in the function, how can I do that?

Comment: You can make them inputs of your function. Please read how to declare inputs of a [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: Maybe as a small addition, you can use run("MyScript.m") to execute the statements in the script file MyScript.m. This will ensure that the variable from the Matlab script exist in the workspace and can thus be used as function input. Or alternative, convert the second Matlab script to a function as well and make it output the variables of interest.

Comment: @HannoReuvers Just typing `MyScript` has the same effect. The only thing `run` does is change the current directory to the one that contains the file pointed to, if you give its full path, and then change back.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! In the future, that'll save me some typing when running a script in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them [global variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html).

Comment: This is literally the worst possible solution to the problem.

Comment: I too hate global variables. But without further information, I think this is the most direct answer to the question.

Comment: Yes,  the question does not have nearly sufficient information to be answered. But even the first comment under the question has a better suggestion than using globals.  Globals have their uses, passing values to a function is not one of them.